# String Comparison error in a android code

Tags: android, string, sqlite, logic

I am using the simple code for Sqlite database saving and retrieval. My problem is my code takes always the else part even the strings are same. 
         `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No UName: "+utext+","+str+"; Pswd: "+ptext+","+str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

instead of,
    `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes UName: "+utext+","+str+"; Pswd: "+ptext+","+str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

I checked the output with toast and with debug mode. The value of utext is equal to str and the value of ptext is equal to str1. Is anything I made mistake here? I don't find anything.

[http://postimg.org/image/huvmxhgup/](http://postimg.org/image/huvmxhgup/][1])

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            utext=t1.getText().toString();
            ptext=t2.getText().toString();

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tbl_name+" WHERE USERNAME= '"+utext+"' AND PASSWORD= '"+ptext+"'", null);
              if(c.moveToLast() ) {
                      str=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("USERNAME"));
                      str1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "True : "+str+", "+str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
              else
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FALSE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              if(str==utext || str1==ptext)
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes UName: "+utext+","+str+"; Pswd: "+ptext+","+str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              else
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No UName: "+utext+","+str+"; Pswd: "+ptext+","+str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In java, `==` compares the object references and not the content.**

> `==` checks whether two strings are the same object,whereas
>   `.equals()` or `.compareTo()` checks whether the two strings have the
>   same value.

You can either use the method `.equals()` or `.compareTo()` in java to compare strings

Thus, Replace

```
if(str==utext || str1==ptext)
```

with

```
if(str.equals(utext) || str1.equals(ptext))
```

or

```
if(str.compareTo(utext)==0 || str1.compareTo(ptext)==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `.equals()` for String comparison. Change your code to this.

```
if(str.equals(utext) || str1.equals(ptext))
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes UName: "+utext+","+str+"; Pswd: "+ptext+","+str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No UName: "+utext+","+str+"; Pswd: "+ptext+","+str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```